# Storing numeric values as varchar in Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-timestream

I am aiming for cost-efficiency in my data handling practices with Timestream, so I have been trying to decide how best to store numeric values that have a range on the lower side (less than 8 digits).

If I have understood the documentation correct, VARCHAR entries are stored as UTF-8 strings, so a low numeric value will take up less space as a VARCHAR than a BIGINT, which is 64-bit. As such, any column I expect to have a low value is stored as a VARCHAR instead of BIGINT. I imagine this has some potential querying implications, however, so I was hoping that someone may be able to enlighten me as to the downsides. Already, when integrating with a Grafana dashboard, I have realized that it does not recognize the VARCHAR as a numeric value, so continuing with my current practice will require me to do some casting. Am I correct on how it will be stored? Is it worth the hassle, however?

Comment: a big int need 8 bytes for 8 digits number with utf8 mb4 you need 32 bytes, so number are saved as numbers as this needs the lowest size

Comment: Is a digit not stored in a single byte? IBM docs seem to suggest so, unless I am mistaken: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=unicode-utfs

Comment: no utf8 mb3 needs 3 bytes even when they are 0 and utf8 mb4 needs 4 bytes